# Windows performance index of Surface Book

Tags: windows-10, performance, microsoft-surface, windows-experience-index

I recently bought a new Surface Book, and I would like to carry out a test to make sure my new laptop meets the standard. The specifications are:

6th Gen Intel Core i5-6300U, 2.4GHz, 128MB Intel HD Graphics 520
256GB SSD
8GB RAM

I ran a Windows Experience Index test using this website,
[Windows Performance Test link](https://www.myfavoritegadgets.info/tipstricks/WEIwin81.html)

And I got a not so good score.
WinSPR

SystemScore 5.6
MemoryScore 7.7
CpuScore 7.1
CpuSubAggScore 7.5
VideoEncodeScore 6.6
GraphicsScore 5.6
Dx9SubScore 9.9
Dx10SubScore 9.9
GamingScore 9.9
StdDefPlaybackScore True
HighDefPlayBackScore True
DiskScore 8.6

Does that mean my computer is faulty? The system score only got 5.6. My old Retina MacBook Pro 2013 late runs on Bootcamp scored 6.9, which is better than my new Microsoft surface book. I don't really expect an old machine outperform a new Microsoft modern CPU processor. And is there a reference score that a new surface book obtain so that i can compare with?

Comment: Windows Performance Index is flawed, as not only are there maximums on the scores you can get (which i believe is 9.9 here), but the system score just takes the lowest of all the other scores. Do you *actually* have a performance problem with your laptop?

Comment: I posted an answer. your old MacBook seams to have a faster GPU, so that is why you got higher values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Windows Performance index performed by WinSAT takes the lowest value as SystemScore. Your lowest value is 5.6 for Graphics Score, so the System Score is also 5.6.

This is expected, because the Intel HD 520 is not a fast GPU and it looks like your older MacBook Pro had a discrete GPU (nVIDIA or AMD) which is faster comapred to the Intel HD in the CPU. But the index is not really helpful and this is why Microsoft ditched it in Windows 8.1 from the GUI and you need to run WinSAT from cmd.